# Proving an Integral 0

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, complex-integration

$$\large I(s)= \int_1^\infty\psi(x)(x^{\frac{1-s}{2}}-x^{\frac{\overline{s}}{2}})\frac{dx}{x}$$ where $s\in \mathbb{C}$ and $\psi (x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}$ ,  $\overline{s}$ denotes the complex conjugate

Prove that $I(s)=0$ when $0<\Re(s)<1$

**My try**:

$I(1/2+it)=\int_1^\infty\psi(x)(x^{\frac{1/2-it}{2}}-x^{\frac{1/2-it}{2}})\frac{dx}{x}$

$I(1/2+it)=0 \ \forall \  t\in \mathbb{R}$

So, $I(s)=0$ for infinitely many values of $s$

Comment: Just as a comment for others reading the post, the second place $s$ appears above is $\overline{s}$. I didn't see it at first (its pretty small) so hopefully this prevents others from missing it

Comment: this is simply not true - if $s=a<1/2$ real then the integrand is positive on $(1,\infty)$ hence the integral is positive; by continuity, the fact that the integral is non zero holds for nearby $s$ non-real too; similarly for $s=a>1/2$ the integral is negative so it is non-zero for nearby non-real $s$;

Comment: @Conrad What if s is a complex number and not a real number?

Comment: Is this related to the Riemann hypothesis? :)

Comment: that's exactly what I have shown, that the integral is non-zero for a lot of complex (non-real) numbers by continuity; as an exercise, you should prove that the integral cannot vanish on any open set in the plane (and if you cannot, better go back to the drawing board and learn some complex analysis before keeping asking the same questions again and again)